# Moving the scroll bar horizontally using keys in Eclipse Neon console view?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-neon

Is it possible to use the arrow keys to move the scroll bar horizontally in the Eclipse Neon console view?

Comment: I'm confused as to how this is a programming question.

Comment: It's related to tooling used for programming.